# Show dynamically tooltip after mouseon event in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to show tooltip dynamically after `mouseon` event in JSF. Also I need to call a java method on `mouseon` event in datatable row.

Here what I have tried:

```
<p:ajax event="mouseover" actionListener="#{buyerWalletView.testMethod)}"/>


public void testMethod(ActionEvent ev) throws IOException {
    if (ev.getSource() != null && ev.getSource() instanceof HtmlDataTable) {
        HtmlDataTable objHtmlDataTable = (HtmlDataTable) ev.getSource();
        System.out.println(objHtmlDataTable.getRowIndex());
    }
}
 
 // for tooltip:
  
    <p:column width="150">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{lbl['wallet.platform']}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{cartItem.platformType}"/>
        <p:tooltip for="walletHistoryTable"
                   value="test"/>
    </p:column>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PF version? What do you need to display with the tooltip, a static or a dynamic text? The tooltip is for which element, cells (you can use column title), others? Have you tried with pure js (a listener for the element with hover class that do stuff or call server)

Comment: i need to call java bean on hover. And show it on the tooltip. So i should not use js i think.

Comment: The column title attribute isn't enough? Else, from js you can call a remote command, that calls your bean/server.